# How to replace dash between characters with space using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace dashes which appear between letters with a space using regex. For example to replace `ab-cd` with `ab cd`

The following matches the character-character sequence, however also replaces the characters  [i.e. `ab-cd` results in `a d`, rather than `ab cd` as i desire]

```
 new_term = re.sub(r"[A-z]\-[A-z]", " ", original_term)
```

How i adapt the above to only replace the `-` part?

Comment: Can you do this by simple replacing `-` with a space in the given string? Is using regex necessary?

Comment: @JeffBridgman  yes - i only want to replace when the dash occurs between characters, and not when between space. i.e. to replace `ab-cd`, but not to change `ab - cd` - [`replace` doesn't have that control].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to capture the characters **before** and **after** the `-` to a group and use them for replacement, i.e.:

```
import re
subject = "ab-cd"
subject = re.sub(r"([a-z])\-([a-z])", r"\1 \2", subject , 0, re.IGNORECASE)
print subject
#ab cd
```

---

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/LAYQWT

---

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```
([A-z])\-([A-z])

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([A-z])»
   Match a single character in the range between “A” and “z” «[A-z]»
Match the character “-” literally «\-»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «([A-z])»
   Match a single character in the range between “A” and “z” «[A-z]»

\1 \2

Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
Insert the character “ ” literally « »
Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 2 «\2»
```

Answer (score 5):

Use references to capturing groups:

```
>>> original_term = 'ab-cd'
>>> re.sub(r"([A-z])\-([A-z])", r"\1 \2", original_term)
'ab cd'
```

This assumes, of course, that you can't just do `original_term.replace('-', ' ')` for whatever reason. Perhaps your text uses hyphens where it should use en dashes or something.

Comment: You shouldn't use `[A-z]` since regex ranges uses ascii table index. For this specific range you will match `A-Z[\]^_\`a-z`. However, you can use `(?i)` if you want to use `a-z` as key insensitive. For instance, you can have `(?i)([a-z])\-([a-z])`. Anyway, I know OP original regex is that... but just saying.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use look-arounds:

```
 new_term = re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Za-z])-(?=[A-Za-z])", " ", original_term)
```

Or capturing groups:

```
 new_term = re.sub(r"([A-Za-z])-(?=[A-Za-z])", r"\1 ", original_term)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/kn6ppB)

Note that `[A-z]` also matches some non-letters (namely `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, and `` ` ``), thus, I suggest replacing it with `[A-Z]` and use a case-insensitive modifier `(?i)`.

Note that you do not have to escape a hyphen outside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub()` always replaces the whole matched sequence with the replacement.

A solution to only replace the dash are *lookahead* and *lookbehind* assertions. They don't count to the matched sequence.

```
new_term = re.sub(r"(?<=[A-z])\-(?=[A-z])", " ", original_term)
```

The syntax is explained in the [Python documentation for the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score -1):

I think there's a simple way to replace dashes using Visual Basic, in a multiline textbox:

```
Regex.Replace(ReadText.Text, "[-]", " ")
```

Comment: This may be accurate, but it's not Python, which is what this question is about.